# set same width to all columns for dynamically created jqGrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

The following code, binds data to the JQGrid dynamically and shows up the data correctly in case of large columns are displayed into the grid:

```
$('#divJQGridShowResult').jqGrid({
    jsonReader: {
        cell: "cell",
        id: "id"
    },
    datatype: 'jsonstring',
    mtype: 'post',
    datastr: colD,
    colModel: colM,
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    viewrecords: true
});
```

But, when i have only two columns that are displayed into the grid, the width of the columns of **header and grid data varies**.
Please see the below snapshot

[image]

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

In the `colM`, set `fixed` as `true`, and furthermore, set `width` in pixels for every column.

Comment: i have populated colM dynamically and it is returning data, can you give some code that will explicitly set the width equally

Comment: From the [API](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options), please see the 'fixed' and 'width' properties that need to be added explicitly for every dynamically created column.